# checking the internet connection all the time on android

Tags: android

I want to develop a project , in this project I will use the internet all the time , when the internet connection is gone , the user will be warned and the screen will be paused . When the internet is available , the user will be able to continue from the previous state of the app . I am new to android programming.. I am thinking of using THREADS , but I am not sure . Should I use threads or is there something that you suggest ? I will be thankful for your comments .

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if `Connection` is available in some custom *intervals* for example. So you can use this snippet of code:

```
private boolean isConnectionAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

for check if Connection is available or not. If it will return `false` so then you can show meant `AlertDialog` or something.

Then you need to add *permissions*:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

And for check it in some intervals you can use for your goal [`AlarmManager`](http://android-er.blogspot.cz/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html), meant [`Threads`](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html), [`TimerTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)

Comment: I have already checked the network connection already in a different code & it is working =) , I was just not sure about using THREADS to process the app. all the tiaccording to the existence of the net . Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The better solution will be to register a broadcast receiver for `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`. The `onReceive()` will be called every time any changes in connectivity occur. There is a `ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY` field which tells you that the connection is not available at the moment. You can check its value and proceed as your logic requires. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you usually check for Internet Connection in `Android`

```
private boolean checkInternetConnection() 
{
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting();

boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();

boolean gprs=manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting();

if (is3g || isWifi) 
{
    Log.v(TAG,"3G/WIFI connection is present");
    return true;
}
else if(gprs)
 { 
     Log.v(TAG,"gprs connection is present");
     return true;
 }

 return false;

}
```

You need to add appropriate permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

I think you need not use `Threads` for this.

For more info refer [ConnectivityManager for Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html).